# Add bootstrap active class to a button if clicked but will be removed if clicked on another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple buttons for date filtering. I'm showing records based on the button selected. Now I want to add the bootstrap active class to a button if clicked. Otherwise it won't be active and If we click another button then that will be active and then active class of the previous button will be removed. Following are my buttons :-

```
<div class="top_stats_wrapper">
    <div class="right-side">
        <form method="get" >
            <input type="hidden" name="time" value="today" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mright5 test pull-left display-block" id="today" onclick="showAll('today')">Today</button>
        </form>
        <form method="get" >
            <input type="hidden" name="time" value="week" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mright5 test pull-left display-block " id="week" onclick="showAll('week')">This Week</button>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
```

Following code I have tried to add active class:-

```
function showAll(time = '', from_date = '', to_date = ''){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {time:time,from_date:from_date,to_date:to_date},
        url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/home/top_stats') ?>',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#top_stats').html(data);
            if($("#today").hasClass("active")){
                $("#today").removeClass("active");
            }else {
                $("#today").addClass("active");
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: In what way does your code doesn't work? Does it add a class? Does it throw an error?

Comment: You should be using classes for groups of like elements whenever possible. It dramatically simplifies things.

Comment: Errorname It adds the class without even clicking that's my problem.

Comment: You mean: When you click on "This week", it adds a "active" to "Today" ?

Comment: +isherwood can give me an example. I'm having hard time to actually do it.

Comment: +Errorname By default it selects today. I want today to be deselected if I click week.

Comment: Is showAll called at other times? Try logging inside the function to be sure it's called only on button click

Comment: errorname showAll() gets called from $(document).ready(function ()

Comment: Because showAll() is called when the document is ready, then it will execute the ajax and (hopefully) the `success` method. Which means it will test if #today has the active class, and if not, it will add it.

Comment: This explains why it selects today without you clicking

Comment: +errorname so What's the solution??